# Чтение COM порта

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как можно на C# прочитать данные с COM порта, загвоздка в том, что данные переменной длины. Если можно, с примером. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А с чтением данных известной длины проблем нет?

Comment: Да вроде не пробовал, задачи такой нет.

Comment: C# и ком... возможно. Только вот нужно ли? Вы лучше опишите, что вызывает затруднения. И с каким у-вом собираетесь сопрягать ПК.

Answer (score 2):

Если возникают такие проблемы - то устройство не правильно спроектировано. По первым байтам (заголовок пакета) вы уже должны знать сколько байт осталось прочитать. Даже если вы и будете читать все байты, как узнать когда нужно начать обработку пакета ?

Обычно читают заголовок пакета (1-3 байта) за ним следует длина пакета, которую мы и должны прочитать.

Comment: > Даже если вы и будете читать все байты, как узнать когда нужно начать обработку пакета ?

Варианты - по таймауту, по приходу STOP-комбинации данных.